# Problem with namespace from a nested folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a problem using a namespaced component which works in some places but not others:

Pages/Transactions/List.razor

```
<Test @ref="Test1"></Test>
```

Pages/Transactions/List.razor.cs:

```
using Accounting.Web.Components.Test;

namespace Accounting.Web.Pages.Transactions
{
    public partial class List
    {
        private Test Test1 { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

The above reference to Test works as expected.

But then I want to to use the Test component in another component, so I do the following:

Components/Transactions/TRansactionRules/TRansactionRules.razor.cs

```
using Accounting.Web.Components.Test:

namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Transactions.TransactionRules
{
    public partial class TransactionRules
    {
        [Parameter]
        public Test Test1 { get; set; } = default!;  // error
    }
}
```

But using it in the component above produces the following error:

```
"Test" is a namespace but used as a type
```

At which point I have to replace the line with:

```
public Accounting.Web.Components.Test.Test Test1 { get; set; } = default!;
```

while elsewhere I can refer to it as **Accounting.Web.Components.Test**

It seems the folder / file structure has something to with it:

```
+Pages
 +Transactions
  -List.razor
  -List.razor.cs

+Components
 +Test
  -Test.razor
  -Test.razor.cs  

 +Transactions
  +TransactionRules
   -TransactionRules.razor
   -TransactionRules.razor.cs
```

It seems when I try to use the Test component in a another component which is nested in a extra subfolder, reference to it fails, otherwise it will work.

I wish to refer to it as Accounting.Web.Components.Test rather than Test.Test regardless of where it is used.  Am I doing something wrong, if so what?

Comment: [❌ DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces)

Comment: Explicitly namespace everything.  Components could be `@namespace MyApp.UI.Components`.  Don't let the directory structure dictate your namespace.   Use it to organise your files, not your namespaces,

Comment: You'd better change the Test type name to another one.Or you may need to use fully-qualified names.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks, I was under the impression the directory SHOULD dictate the namespace but I'm relieved to have been better informed otherwise.

Comment: Take a look at the DotNetCore Repo on Github.  MS certainly don't use directory structure to dictate their namespaces!

Comment: It is a golden rule to map namespaces to folders. There can be a few exceptions but in general you want to follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the error you are getting is because you are 'using' a namespace which also contains the full name of he type you are trying to use. I think removing **.Test** from the using directive should fix the issue.

```
using Accounting.Web.Components 

namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Transactions.TransactionRules
{
    public partial class TransactionRules
    {
        [Parameter]
        public Test Test1 { get; set; } = default!;  // error
    }
}
```

(optional) You can move below code inside of _Imports.razor file in blazor solution, and outside of your component code. This way it will make it available everywhere into your blazor solution and not just one component file.

```
using Accounting.Web.Components
```